# FastAPI coroutine within thread or thread within coroutine

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, python-multithreading

I am writing a FastAPI application and, for a given path operation, I need call two functions: one is an IO operation that *doesn't* support `async` (let's call it function `A`) and the other one is an IO operation that *does* support `async` (let's call it function `B`). They need to be called sequentially and there is some other *not IO* operation that needs to happen between then. I think I have the following alternatives:

1. Define the path operation with `async` and call `A` as usual, then `await` B.
2. Define the path operation with `async`, run `B` in a threadpool (e.g. `fastapi.concurrency.run_in_threadpool`) and then `await` B.
3. Define the path operation *without* `async`, call `A` as usual and then call `B` using `run_until_complete` from an event loop.

I wonder what is the best option in terms of performance speed. I am sure there may be a lot of subtle details to figure out before giving a definite, like the exact implementation of functions `A` and `B`. However, I was hoping I could find some general understanding of what is going on in this situation and what to do in general if I can't afford running a benchmark to may exact implementations.

Comment: Did you find an answer? Quite interested in this myself.

I believe a key factor would be how long the IO operations are. If you have a long blocking IO operation, then you'll need threading to facilitate any sort of concurrency, but if you have a long async IO operation, then threading won't take full advantage of the thread's downtime, so async is necessary.

Option (2) would take advantage of both frameworks though, so seems that would be best?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I couldn't find any grounded answer, I guess the best we can hope for is "try it for your case and see how it goes".

Answer (score 0):

I think option 1 is generally a better approach in terms of performance and code simplicity. It allows you to handle both synchronous and asynchronous operations without further complications. However, if function A is a major performance bottleneck you might consider using option 2 for function A.